# How to stream the UploadPart S3 operation from an incoming request to AWS S3 using go?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, stream, reverse-proxy, aws-sdk-go

**Context**

With my team we are building a reverse proxy to intercept all outgoing requests to S3 in order to audit and control the access from the different apps.

We've successfully implemented almost all operations by streaming the content of the files. For instance, to upload with single operation we used the `s3manager.Uploader` to stream the body of the incoming request (which is an `io.Reader`) to S3 and to download (both single and multipart flavor) we used the primitive `io.Copy` to write the response from the `s3.GetObjectOutput.Body` (which is an `io.ReadCloser`).

**The problem:**

The only operation we still couldn't implement via streaming was the *upload-part* (in the context of a multipart uploading). The problem is that `s3.UploadPartInput` needs a `aws.ReadSeekCloser` and to pass the body of the incoming request you need to buffer it in some place (for example, in memory).

This is what we have so far:

```
func (ph *VaultProxyHandler) HandleUploadPart(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, s3api s3iface.S3API, bucket string, key string, uploadID string, part int64) {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    
    // here loads the entire body to memory
    if _, err := io.Copy(buf, r.Body); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    payload := buf.Bytes()

    input := &s3.UploadPartInput{
        Bucket:     aws.String(bucket),
        Key:        aws.String(key),
        UploadId:   aws.String(uploadID),
        PartNumber: aws.Int64(part),
        Body:       aws.ReadSeekCloser(bytes.NewReader(payload)),
    }

    output, err := s3api.UploadPart(input)

    // and so on...
}
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to stream an incoming request of an `UploadPart` to S3? (by stream I mean not to store the entire body in memory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a way to reverse-proxy an incoming *UploadPart* with stream processing by building a request using the AWS SDK and signing it with *unsigned payload*.

Here a basic example:

```
type AwsService struct {
    Region   string
    S3Client s3iface.S3API
    Signer   *v4.Signer
}

func NewAwsService(region string, accessKey string, secretKey string, sessionToken string) (*AwsService, error) {
    creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(accessKey, secretKey, sessionToken)
    awsConfig := aws.NewConfig().
        WithRegion(region).
        WithCredentials(creds).
        WithCredentialsChainVerboseErrors(true)
    sess, err := session.NewSession(awsConfig)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    svc := s3.New(sess)

    signer := v4.NewSigner(creds)
    v4.WithUnsignedPayload(signer)

    return &AwsService{
        Region:   region,
        S3Client: svc,
        Signer:   signer,
    }, nil
}

func (s *AwsService) UploadPart(bucket string, key string, part int, uploadID string, payloadReader io.Reader, contentLength int64) (string, error) {

    input := &s3.UploadPartInput{
        Bucket:        aws.String(bucket),
        Key:           aws.String(key),
        UploadId:      aws.String(uploadID),
        PartNumber:    aws.Int64(int64(part)),
        ContentLength: aws.Int64(contentLength),
        Body:          aws.ReadSeekCloser(payloadReader),
    }

    req, output := s.S3Client.UploadPartRequest(input)

    _, err := s.Signer.Sign(req.HTTPRequest, req.Body, s3.ServiceName, s.Region, time.Now())
    err = req.Send()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return *output.ETag, nil
}
```

Then, it can be invoked from a handler:

```
func HandleUploadPart(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    query := r.URL.Query()
    region := query.Get("region")
    bucket := query.Get("bucket")
    key := query.Get("key")
    part, err := strconv.Atoi(query.Get("part"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    uploadID := query.Get("upload-id")
    payloadReader := r.Body

    contentLength, err := strconv.ParseInt(r.Header.Get("Content-Length"), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    etag, err := awsService.UploadPart(region, bucket, key, part, uploadID, payloadReader, contentLength)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("ETag", etag)
}
```

Downsides:

- The client must know the content length in advance and send it.
- The payload cannot be signed.